# Cygwin + Ruby (pre-installed) + RubyGems: Is that possible?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, cygwin, capistrano

I've found a lot of questions here on StackOverflow about this, but no one could help me.

I've installed Cygwin (1.7) with Ruby (checked in installation) and then RubyGems (ruby setup.rb). Ok, it's working.

But then when I try to install a gem (like capistrano), I got some errors.

```
$ gem install capistrano -v "3.1.0"

Fetching: capistrano-3.1.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
can't convert nil into String
```

Anyone knows whats happening? o.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed executing `gem install` from CMD and not from Cygwin.
I don't know why, but now it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an alias, to force Cygwin using the batch version of `gem.exe`.
Add this line to your config file `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias gem='gem.bat'
```

And restart your bash:

```
bash
```

You'll then be able to use `gem install` from Cygwin.